# Equivalent code in python (time)

Tags: javascript, python

Javascript code:

```
var date = new Date(1466278504960);
```

return: Sat Jun 18 2016 20:35:04 GMT+0100 (WEST)

How can I convert the same number to date in python ?

When I use

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1466278504960")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

I receive this error: ValueError: year is out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) will do this, but you need to divide the value by `1000` first (the numeric value you give and JavaScript's `Date` expects is in *milliseconds* since the epoch, where Python's API takes a floating point *seconds* since the epoch):

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.fromtimestamp(1466278504960 / 1000.)
```

That makes the raw `datetime` object; if you want it formatted the same, you should take a look at [`datetime` object's `strftime` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Answer (score 0):

It's almost the same. You just have to convert the units.

[Date](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) from javascript specifies the number in milliseconds, in other words, expects a number in millisenconds as a parameter. When the python  [date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#) takes seconds.